# SQL Server 2008 grouping based on 2 columns which contains null values

Tags: sql-server, grouping

My question is in the table structure below. All items grouped by `storeName` and `storeId` then displays the total of each item for each store. But some of the items not sold in some stores therefore displays NULL.. Is that possible to

- display **egg&bacon** instead of `NULL` for the first 8 records in `itemName` column and
- display **coke** for instead of `NULL` the second 8  in `itemName` column and so on.

I do not know the how many item they have. So it is dynamic.

I want to do this because I have created a crosstab report with pentaho report designer. It works fine but it expects data in order to display it properly. So each item must have 8 records, one for each store. So I can group it by store and `itemname`. So the report displays - or 0 for the items not sold for those stores.

what I have

```
storeId  storeName itemName  total
1        storeA    egg&bacon 75
2        storeB    NULL      NULL
3        storeC    egg&bacon 30
4        storeD    NULL      NULL
5        storeE    NULL      NULL
6        storeF    egg&bacon 50
7        storeG    NULL      NULL
8        storeH    NULL      NULL
1        storeA    coke      105
2        storeB    coke      90
3        storeC    coke      60
4        storeD    NULL      NULL
5        storeE    coke      20
6        storeF    coke      80
7        storeG    NULL      NULL
8        storeH    NULL      NULL
```

what I want (If the table below is not realistic, I can create a separate column to group them but again how?)

```
    storeId  storeName itemName  total
    1        storeA    egg&bacon 75
    2        storeB    egg&bacon 0
    3        storeC    egg&bacon 30
    4        storeD    egg&bacon 0
    5        storeE    egg&bacon 0
    6        storeF    egg&bacon 50
    7        storeG    egg&bacon 0
    8        storeH    egg&bacon 0
    1        storeA    coke      105
    2        storeB    coke      90
    3        storeC    coke      60
    4        storeD    NULL      0
    5        storeE    coke      20
    6        storeF    coke      80
    7        storeG    NULL      0
    8        storeH    NULL      0
```

This is the sample SQL statement

```
SELECT storeId , storeName, itemName, total FROM STORE
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT storeId, storeName, itemId,  total FROM REVENUE_CENTER as RVC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MENU_ITEM_TOTAL as MIT ON STORE.storeId = MIT.storeId       
) as subQ ON STORE.storeId = subQ.storeId

LEFT OUTER JOIN MENU_ITEM as MI ON  MI.itemId = subQ.itemId
```

thanks in advance
Oz.

Comment: I also appreciate if anyone suggests an alternative way.

Comment: What's revenue center?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to know you have zero egg&bacon in a store you must at least set the item name to 'egg&bacon'
2. to change null to zero in the total column you can use ISNULL(itemName, 0)
3. since storeid and name are constant you should only keep storeid in the table, and group by it (better performance, less data space) and keep store name in another table. That will change your group by statements to be based only on store ID.
4. Consider not saving records for items shat are now null, null - this is something your code should handle.